# VS Code Color Highlighting Tokenization for certain chars not working

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a syntax highlighting file for VS Code.
While doing this, I wanted to colorize the + sign, however, this won't work somehow.
I tried matching the standard operators like this:
`"match": "\b(\+|-|\*|\/)\b"`
But Addition and Multiplication don't work. When I remove the \ in front of them, it also doesn't work.
The same problem occurs with ||.
Does someone know, how you can match these for the syntax highlighting?

Also, when inspecting the tokens,

```
"operators": {
            "name": "keyword.operator.fwcsv",
            "match": "\\b(-|\/)\\b"
        },
```

doesn't result in a - being shown as a keyword.operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json format used by your tmLanguage grammar file escapes the character after a `\`. Therefore, `\+` is a special character like `\n`, which (I think) does not exist. You have to double the `\` in order to do what you want, so your regex would look like this:

`"match": "\\b(\\+|-|\\*|\\/)\\b"`

Once the grammar has been built, this is equivalent to:

`\b(\+|-|\*|\/)\b`